# How to merge campaign / campaign member fields into email template?

Tags: email, email-template, campaign, campaign-member

I have Campaigns and Campaign Members created with an Eventbrite integration. I need an email sequence to go out via flow or manually with the Send List Email to the campaign members.

The merge fields are not merging. If I use Contact.FirstName, that will merge, but no Campaign fields. I created formula fields to the Campaign Member records to surface the Campaign info I need in the emails (event name, date, campaign name, venue address, etc.) and tried using CampaignMember merge fields from those and the data still doesn't merge in. Furthermore, if I use CampaignMember.FirstName, the name is blank also.

What am I missing here? I searched through questions here and saw that someone used CampaignMember fields which prompted my attempt to surface those fields. I also saw an [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.email_list_email_considerations.htm&type=5) that says Campaign fields cannot merge in List Emails, but what about Campaign Member fields? Is there a workaround? Will they populate in flow?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).  Including a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful. Your verbal description is not enough to troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: Is your email template [based on the CampaignMember object](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000321564&type=1)?